# Bash command with pipe not working in crontab

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I need to delete files under directory except latest 2.

I have prepared command to list according to date and delete files. It work when I run manually from command line , however it does not work in crontab.

In crontab,

```
* * * * * /bin/ls -t /mytest | /usr/bin/tail -n +2 | /usr/bin/xargs rm --
```

This command works when I run this command from commandline.

Also tried to add command in bash script then called that script from crontab but it did not work again.

How can I run that command via crontab?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Explain what does not work; did you see any errors?

Comment: Hi, no any errors - but can see it ran according to cron logs

Comment: what if you try ```bash -c "/bin/ls -t /mytest | /usr/bin/tail -n +2 | /usr/bin/xargs rm --"``` as the command to your cron job?

Comment: no luck , its working from command line again but no in cron job

Comment: Enable crons error logging, e.g. by setting `MAILTO=`.

Answer (score 29):

crontab only expects one command.
If multiple commands are to be executed, they can be bundled using bash -c

```
* * * * * bash -c 'ls -t /mytest | tail -n +2 | xargs rm --'
```

Comment: Probably remove the explicit paths while you're at it.

Comment: is PATH at the beginning of crontab defined?