# I want not to save the logs that are "warning" in the log crontab

Tags: linux, bash, logging, cron, backup

I want not to save the logs that are "warning" in the log file that the crontab creates, I only want the "error" messages, does anyone know how I can exclude these messages?
I have tried doing a grep -v but it doesn't work:

`45  5   *   *   *   /home/username/barc/backupsql.sh 2>&1 | grep -v 'Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.'`

Thanks in advance for anyone trying to help me.

Comment: `Crontab` allows only one command (no pipelines).. You may found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56311070/bash-command-with-pipe-not-working-in-crontab).

Comment: Instead of fiddling with complicated crontab entries, write a small script which implements the logic and put the script invocation into your crontab (i.e. `/usr/bin/bash /path/to/your/script`). It is also easier to debug, because you can test your script outside the crontab context.

Answer (score 0):

Crontab lets you execute 1 scheduled command/script at a time.
Piping the output of your script to Grep command won't work. Furthermore, crontab by default redirects output to dev/null, therefore you won't see the output unless you save it to a file.

I suggest something like this:

1. Edit your script to redirect it's output to a file with your grep command. For example by adding

```
DATE=$(date +"%m_%d_%Y")

some command | grep -v Warning >> /tmp/$DATE.log # Here
```

2. Edit your Cron job to execute the script every day like you did, removing everything after the pipe:

```
45  5   *   *   *   /home/username/barc/backupsql.sh
```

3. In order to monitor the output you could use `tail` command as follows:
   `tail -f /tmp/$DATE.log`